# Как работает выражение i = i++?

Tags: java, инкремент

Есть код:

```
 int i = 1;
 i=i++;
 System.out.println(i);
```

ВНЕЗАПНО

`Output:1`

**Вопрос:** Почему выдаёт единицу? Я считаю, что должна дать двойку. Ну и что что постфиксная запись? Даже если оно сначала бы присвоила `i` единицу, то потом всё равно должно было увеличить значение `i` на единицу.

**PS.** Мне хочется получить ответ по шагам, типа:

1. Сначала оно делает это, потому что...
2. Потом оно делает это, потому что...

Comment: @Denis нет. В механике есть два раздела - динамика, она описывает совместное положение (луна вращается вокруг земли) и кинематика (какого лешего эта луна вращается вокруг земли). На тот вопрос был ответ дан в контексте динамики отчего автор был удовлетворён, а здесь  
требуется кинематика.

Comment: А зачем тебе это? Я бы просто не использовал подобные выражения: есть вероятность, что поведение может быть не определено. По крайней мере, так в C в примере 
int x = 5, y = 6;
int z = x++ + y++;

Comment: @MikhailIonkin понимать хочу одним глазом весь проект, вплоть до того где там в железе какой транзистор открывается.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Возможно понятнее будет на уровне байткода. Ваш код будет скомпилирован в

```
 0: iconst_1             // Загрузить константу 1 в стек
 1: istore_1             // Сохранить значение из стека в локальную переменную i
 2: iload_1              // Загрузить значение локальной переменной i в стек (в стеке 1)
 3: iinc          1, 1   // Увеличить значение локальной переменной i на 1 (в переменной теперь 2)
 6: istore_1             // СОХРАНИТЬ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ИЗ СТЕКА В ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ i (в переменной опять 1)
 7: getstatic     #2
10: iload_1              // Загрузить в стек значение переменной i
11: invokevirtual #3     // Вывести значение
```

Я не нашёл конкретного описания этого поведения в Java Language Specification, но оно не противоречит разделам [15.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) и [15.26.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1) описывающим порядок разбора выражений постинкремента и присваивания.

Comment: Имхо самое интересное.

Comment: Это ничего не объясняет, а лишь показывает байткод реализацию. Объяснением была бы цитата из соответствующего места Java Language Specification.

Comment: Согалсен, с Ростиславом. Пытаюсь понять, что-то не очень доходит. Пояснили бы по каждой команде более развёрнуто. Хотя всё равно очень интересно.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin я тоже согласен с Ростиславом, но к сожалению не помню JLS наизусть.

Answer (score 7):

```
int i = 1;

// вместо i = i++;
int __temp = i;
i = i + 1;
i = __temp;

System.out.println(i);
```

Что происходит в строке

```
i = i++;
```

Сначала вычисляется правая часть. Запоминается значение `i` (равное `1`). Потом значение `i` увеличивается на один. Потом возвращается запомненное значение `1`. Потом выполняется присваивание значения `1` переменной `i`.

Это то же самое, что написано в других ответах.

Comment: Вот самое интересное. А из каких соображений в этой операции есть новая временная переменная?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Это то, что происходит в Вашем коде. Новую переменную заводит компилятор.

Comment: То есть, на этапе компиляции, компилятор транслирует исходный код, в аналог того, что вы написали? А каким он правилом пользуется, можете пояснить? Как он видит?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin боюсь объяснение принципов работы стековых виртуальных машин никак не уместить в один ответ.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Не понял про "правило" ).

Comment: @Igor жаль, что не уместить. "Правило" - подразумевается, что мне бы хотелось понимать алгоритм трансляции в более понятный код высокого уровня.

Answer (score 5):

В вашем примере используется post-increment (`i++`), в этом случае вы сначала получите старое значение, а уже затем добавите один к текущему значению(`++`). Чтобы получить 2 необходимо использовать pre-increment: `++i` (прошу заметить инкремент перед именем переменной).

Comment: Не понятно. Распишите эквивалент, если понимаете.

Answer (score 4):

Вот смотрите, такой код:

```
 int i = 1;
    i = i++;
    int a = i;
    System.out.println(a + "" + i);
    int b = i++;
    System.out.println(b + "" + i);
```

выводит

```
11 // обратите внимание, что i снова вернулось значение 1
12 // i уже равно 2, но b получает старое значение i
```

то есть, выражение N=i++ действительно увеличивает i на единицу, но переменной N будет присвоено значение, которое было у i до увеличения - по такому закону работает постфикс.

"Изюминка" в вашем вопросе состоит в том, что переменную i вы действительно увеличили на единицу, но потом "внезапно" той же переменной i присвоили значение, которое было до увеличения - и переменная i у вас снова стала равна 1.

Ответ "по шагам": причина такого результата в следующем - сначала делается операция увеличения i на единицу, а потом делается операция присвоения левой переменной значения i, которое было вначале. Если и слева и справа одна и та же переменная, то вторая операция естественно "затирает" все предыдущие операции.

Answer (score 1):

Дружище для начала надо понять как работает оператор ++ есть

```
int i = 1;

 OperatorPlusPlus(i);

     int OperatorPlusPlus(int yourNumber){
              int tmp = yourNumber;
              int yourNumber = yourNumber + 1;
               return tmp;
    }
```

То есть вы получаете значение переменной tmp и i у вас равна 2, далее вы i (2) присваивание значение tmp(1)

Comment: `int OperatorPlusPlus(int yourNumber){`
а где в теле встречается `int yourNumber` можете поправить? И если возможно, дайте пожалуйста ссылку на источник, о том, что ++ работает именно так.

Comment: На самом деле мы на уроке делали колесо использую с++ , есть такая вещь как перегрузка операторов (не знаю есть ли это в джаве), с помощью ее можно перегружать операторы (++, +, -...) Если вам нужна реализация на с++ могу скинуть позже

Comment: +ost1m1ron у вас в теле цикла ошибка, вы видите? наверно нужно ёнамбер на i заменить. Что касается реализации, то похоже я тупой. Столько людей понимают, как это работает, а я - не очень.

Comment: писал через телефон извиняюсь

Comment: Example Example ::operator ++ ()
{
 int tmp = this->i;
 this->i = this->i + 1;
 return tmp;
}
написан на с++

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 1; // i=1
i++        // i=2, значение выражения 1
i = ...;   // присвоить 1 в переменную i - получается i=1
```

Comment: ЙаНифигаНеПонял

Comment: Отладчик в зубы и дебажь по шагам.

Comment: "Отладчик в зубы и дебажь по шагам"
Вот за это я и не люблю русский SO.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, у меня написаны в ответе 3 шага: присвоить, сделать инкремент, присвоить. И я понятия не имею, что в этих трёх шагах может быть непонятно.

Comment: Не понятен эквивалент операции инкремент, выраженный на ассемблере в контексте присвоения переменной самой себе.

Comment: У меня в ответе нет ассемблера.