# Проблема с инкрементом С#

Tags: c#

Если посчитать, то получается, что в 15-й строке x = -8++. 
Почему второй х тоже = -8, если должно быть х= -8 + 1=-7???

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("1-е уравнение");
            int x = 10, y = 12, z = 3;
            Console.WriteLine(x += y - x++ * z);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот консоль вывода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `x += y - x++ * z` никто в реальности не пишет такой код именно потому, что потом в нем черт ногу сломит. Если вы сами не можете понять, как работает код. что вы написали, попробуйте его сперва упростить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что это

```
Console.WriteLine(x += y - x++ * z);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

все равно что это

```
// x += y - x++ * z - is the same as x = x + (y - x++ * z)

int __temp1 = x; // __temp1 is 10
x++; // x is 11
x = __temp1 + (y - __temp1 * z); // in brackets -18, x is -8

Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Присваивание вычисленного значения иксу, происходит после завершения всех манипуляций с правой частью.

[Как работает выражение i = i++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887868/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-i-i)