# Проблема с генератором чисел в процедуре!

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Сделал процедуру для вывода матрицы, заполняемая генератором случайных чисел, но она выводит три матрицы и всегда А=В=С или А=В и не равно С, или А не равно В=С.(код не меняю)
В чем проблема ?

```
    Program Lab5_1;
type miniarr = array[1..20,1..20] of integer;  
var A,B,C,M: miniarr;
    n: integer;


procedure array_output (k:integer;D: miniarr);
 var i,j:byte;
 begin
        randomize;
        for i := 1 to k do
           begin
            for j:=1 to k do
              begin
                  D[i,j]:= random(10);
                  write(D[i,j]:5);
              end;
            writeln;
           end; 
    end;

begin
  repeat 
      begin 
       write('Введите целое число N,которое больше 0,чтоб определить матрицы A, B, C(NxN): ');
       read(n);
      end;
  until n>0;
  writeln ('Вывод массива A: ');
  array_output(n,A);
  writeln ('Вывод массива B: ');
  array_output(n,B);
  writeln ('Вывод массива C: ');
  array_output(n,C);


end.
```

Вод скрины вывода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слишком быстро вызывается `randomize`.

```
procedure array_output (k:integer;D: miniarr);
var 
  i, j: byte;
begin
  //randomize;
  ...
end;

randomize;

array_output(n,A);
array_output(n,B);
array_output(n,C);
```

---

Вы вот тут ничего не забыли сделать?

[Проблема с инкрементом С#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/898422/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%A1)

Comment: А что я должен сделать? Я недавно на данном портале и не очень разбираюсь.

Comment: @ANGRYSHARKknyaz2000 Слева от ответа есть знак "галочка", который доступен только автору вопроса. Подходящий ответ следует отметить этим знаком как принятый.

Comment: Спасибо. И еще вопрос по данной теме. Почему если вообще убрать randomize, то программа все равно работает?

Comment: @ANGRYSHARKknyaz2000 Она работает, но работает каждый раз одинаково. А с `randomize;` - каждый раз по-разному.