# Проблема с односвязным списком Pascal

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net, односвязный-список

Нужно написать программы, которая будет проверять есть ли в списке хотя бы два одинаковых элемента. 
Вот код, который написал я, но в 99 строке есть ошибка, но не пойму в чем.

```
uses crt;

type
  PList = ^TList;
  TList = record
    Inf: integer;
    Link: PList;
  end;

 var P, D, Q, G: Plist;
     n: integer;

//создание нового списка(пустого)
procedure InitList(var Head: PList);
begin
  Head := nil;
end;

//Добавление эл-та в конец списка
procedure AddInEnd(var head: PList);
var
  q, t: Plist;
  Elem: integer;
begin
  write('Элемент:');
  readln(Elem);
  t := head;
  while t^.Link <> nil do
  begin
    t := t^.Link;
  end;
  New(q);
  q^.inf := Elem;
  q^.Link := nil;
  t^.Link := q;
end;


//Заполняем список
procedure SozdList(var f: integer; var Head: PList);
var
  q: Plist;
  Elem, i: integer;
begin
  InitList(head);
  write('Кол-во эл-тов в списке:');
  readln(f);
  for i := 1 to f do
    if head = nil
    then
    begin
      write('Элемент:');
      readln(Elem);
      New(q);
      head := q;
      q^.inf := Elem;
      q^.Link := nil;
    end
    else
      AddInEnd(head);
end;


//Вывод данных
procedure Print(Head: Plist);
var
  q: Plist;
begin
  write('Элементы списка:');
  q := Head;
  if q = nil
    then writeln('Список пуст')
  else repeat
      write(q^.inf, ' ');
      q := q^.Link;
    until q = nil;
  writeln;
end;

//Проверка повторных эл-тов
procedure checing(Head: PList);
var i, j: byte;
    D,F: PList;
    flag: boolean;
begin
    F:= Head;
    flag:= false;
    for i:=1 to n do
      begin
        for j:= 1 to (n-i) do
          begin
            F:=F^.Link; //СТОКА 99
            if Head^.Inf = F^.Inf
              then 
                begin
                  writeln('Есть минимум одна пара одинаковых эл-тов!');
                  flag:=true;
                  break;
                end;

          end;
        Head:=Head^.Link;
        if flag = true
          then break;
      end;
    if flag = false
      then writeln('Нет ни одной пары одинаковых эл-тов!');
end;

 begin
  SozdList(n, P);
  Print(P);
  checing(P);



  while P <> nil do
  begin
    D := P;
    P := P^.Link;
    dispose(D);
  end;
 end.
```

Вот то, что выводит консоль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скопируйте строку с ошибкой, тут не отображаются номера строк

Comment: if Head^.Inf = F^.Inf

Comment: Я её отметил в коде комментарием + прикрепил скрин консоли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этой строчке `F` равно `nil`. Должно быть

```
F := Head^.Link;
```

---

Вы здесь ничего не забыли сделать? -
[Проблема с инкрементом С#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/898422/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%A1)

и здесь - 
[Проблема с генератором чисел в процедуре!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/902655/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5)